# How to speed up updation of products data to Bigcommerce store using Bigcommerce Api?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

```
$mysql = mysql_query("select * from `bctablename`") or die(mysql_error()); 
$rows = mysql_num_rows($mysql);
if($rows > 0) { //product exist in merge file

$product_details = mysql_fetch_array($mysql);
$product_info = array('price' => $product_details['price'],
'cost_price' => $product_details['cost_price'],
'retail_price' => $product_details['retail_price'],
'sale_price' => $product_details['sale_price'],
'bin_picking_number' =>$product_details['bin_picking_no'],
'availability_description' => $product_availability,
'availability' => 'available'); 
Bigcommerce_Api::updateProduct($result['product_id'], $product_info);
}
```

I have used above simple query to fetch the product details from our 
database table (fetched all the products from bigcommerce using Api) 
and to update products in BC store using API.

It's taking 1 hour to update 600 - 700 products only. But as per bigcommerce support 20,000 products are to be updated per hour. As I am developing an application  (using Bigcommerce Api) which deals with bulk data ( approx 40,000 products) its taking huge time to update.

Please advice me how to make the process faster.

Comment: *updation is not a word. Otherwise, can't help you sorry.